# "Add as Library" button missing?

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to add external library jars to my project, but imports still don't work. Tutorials keep telling me to click "Add as library", but I don't have that option:

[image: Missing Add as Library button]

But I did add them through Module Settings...

[image: Module Settings]

I also added the 2 .jar files to: /src/main/libs/ and added this to build.gradle inside 'app'.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    --> compile files('src/main/libs/jsonbeans-0.5.jar')
    --> compile files('src/main/libs/kryo-2.23.1-SNAPSHOT-all-debug.jar')
}
```

What else can I try to fix this?
I don't understand why imports just don't work since the files are included in my build.gradle.

**Edit: After changing the directory from `/src/main/libs/` to `/libs/` directly, nothing changed. Imports still do not work.**

Comment: What do you mean in your edit? Can you show the resulting directory structures after this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `libs` folder should be a subfolder of `app`. Instead you have it buried in `app/src/main`. Note that you already have a dependency for the `libs` folder if you put it in the correct place.

When you use a file manager or the command line to move files to your Android Studio project, you sometimes need to synchronize the folder structure by right clicking in the Project pane and clicking Synchronize in the popup menu.

Comment: I just tried this but this did not change the situation. Imports still don't work. I changed the dependencies to `compile files('libs/jsonbeans-0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/kryo-2.23.1-SNAPSHOT-all-debug.jar')`

Comment: @SikuliXUser `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` already takes care of it. You don't need to add any other dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the headsup! Removing the 2 lines didn't change the situation, though.. as expected

Comment: @SikuliXUser Did you move the JARs to `libs` in the root folder of your project?

Comment: Yes I did! I put them in <projectname>/libs and in <projectname>/app/libs.

Comment: @SikuliXUser it should be `<project>/app/libs`. If you move the files outside of Android Studio (with Windows Explorer, for example) you need to right click in the Project pane and click Synchronize in the menu.

Comment: That worked! I feel really stupid for thinking it didn't need any kind of synchronization. Thank you very much!!